# react-doc-viewer for spreadsheets

Tags: reactjs, file, spreadsheet

I need to pass a dynamic url :

```
const docs = [
   { uri: `${API}/${path}/name`}
 ];
<DocViewer
       pluginRenderers={DocViewerRenderers}
       documents={docs}
       config={{
         header: {
           disableHeader: true,
           disableFileName: true,
           retainURLParams: true
         }
       }}
       style={{ height: 1000 }}
     />
```

I get this error "An error occurred
We're sorry, but for some reason we can't open this for you."

I tried using a blob based on the example they have and it didn't work for me.

Is there a way to display pdf and spreadsheets on the page with react?